# Avoid write manually Test Cases with Kiwi-tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Is it possible to write automatically test cases with the tool kiwi-tcms ?
write the automated code for testing and then connect it to the Kiwi API to send that test case ?
https://kiwitcms.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/automation-frameworks.html

> Kiwi TCMS can be used with test automation frameworks. Test names and results are fetched automatically from the test automation framework using a plugin! This is an additional software package that you have to install in your test environment and configure it to talk back to Kiwi TCMS.

**Available plugins**

- tap-plugin: for reading Test Anything Protocol (TAP) files. Written
  in Python
- junit.xml-plugin: for reading junit.xml formatted files.
  Written in Python
- Native JUnit 5 plugin written in Java
- Robot Framework plugin
- Django test runner plugin